# Select dynamically created <select option> with php variable

Tags: php, javascript

Yesterday I learned how to create a select option dynamically with javascript:

```
<select name="dateformat" onchange="change_date();" id="dateformat">
</select>

var dateformat = document.getElementById('dateformat');
dateformat.options[dateformat.options.length] = new Option(month + "/" + day + "/" + fullyear, "M/d/yyyy");
dateformat.options[dateformat.options.length] = new Option(monthwz + "/" + daywz + "/" + fullyear,"MM/dd/yyyy");
dateformat.options[dateformat.options.length] = new Option(day + "/" + month + "/" + fullyear,"d/M/yyyy");
```

I don't know if this is the only way to do this and the javascript code cannot be included in the  code block, but I don't know how to select the appropriate option. From php I query the setting of the user which is e.g. MM/dd/yyyy so I need the second option to be selected when the page loads.

I can do this by static select options e.g.

```
<option value="Business" <?php if($category == 'Business'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> >Business</option>
```

But in this case the select option is dynamically created.

Comment: You could use `selectedIndex` on the `select` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your code to be more elegant:

```
var dateformat = document.getElementById("dateformat"),
    options = [{
        text: month + "/" + day + "/" + fullyear,
        value: "M/d/yyyy"
    }, {
        text: monthwz + "/" + daywz + "/" + fullyear,
        value: "MM/dd/yyyy"
    }, {
        text: day + "/" + month + "/" + fullyear,
        value: "d/M/yyyy"
    }];

for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    var option = options[i],
        element = new Option(option.text, option.value);

    dateformat.options[dateformat.options.length] = element;
}

// one way to set the selected value:
dateformat.value = <?php print json_encode($value); ?>;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vPerj/